# Not saving .txt file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text, streamwriter

Cutting to the chase:

```
Function Create(ByVal network, ByVal location, ByVal type, ByVal requirement1, ByVal requirement2, ByVal requirement3, ByVal name)
    Dim net As String = network
    Dim loc As String = location
    Dim typ As String = type
    Dim nam As String = name
    Dim req1 As String = requirement1
    Dim req2 As String = requirement2
    Dim req3 As String = requirement3
    Dim Mission As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\" & nam & ".txt")
    Mission.WriteLine("Name: " & net)
    Mission.WriteLine("Network: " & net)
    Mission.WriteLine("Location: " & loc)
    Mission.WriteLine("Type: " & typ)
    Mission.WriteLine("Requirement: " & req1)
    Mission.WriteLine("Requirement: " & req2)
    Mission.WriteLine("Requirement: " & req3)
    Mission.Close()
    Console.WriteLine("Written")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
End Function
```

No errors appear, but neither does the file in the filepath. I have it all declared when I call the function, so I know that its not the problem.
Help? :)

Comment: Step through it with a debugger. Looks like your suppressing or loosing an exception.

Comment: I've imported all the systems necessary aswell.

Comment: I see a `nam` and a `name`. Start with `Dim fName = "C:\" & nam & ".txt"` and debug it.

Comment: @JasonRobertNoe i tried your code it is working. i mean it writes the contents to the file...

Comment: I'm still not finding any errors.
@JamalAbdulNasir It works for you?

Comment: @JasonRobertNoe yes, it does. tell me when you run the code don't you see the contents in the file?

Comment: @JamalAbdulNasir I don't see the file at all. It prints "Written", I go to my C:\ drive and there is not a trace that it was ever there.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are using VS2005 or earlier and running it on a version of Windows newer than XP.  You can't write files to the C:\ folder anymore.

Comment: Where can I write to a universal place then?
I'm using VB2010 Express...

Comment: Dim dir as String  
dir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)  

Nevermind. Found a way.

Comment: My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments also works. P.S. You should also call mission.Dispose() to release system resources used by the stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Create(ByVal network As String, ByVal location As String, 
    ByVal type As String, ByVal requirement1 As String, 
    ByVal requirement2 As String, ByVal requirement3 As String,
    ByVal name As String)

    Dim net As String = network
    Dim loc As String = location
    Dim typ As String = type
    Dim nam As String = name
    Dim req1 As String = requirement1
    Dim req2 As String = requirement2
    Dim req3 As String = requirement3
    If Not nam.EndsWith(".txt") Then
        nam &= ".txt"
    End If
    Dim Mission As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Path.Combine(
      System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
      System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), nam))
    Mission.WriteLine("Name: " & net)
    Mission.WriteLine("Network: " & net)
    Mission.WriteLine("Location: " & loc)
    Mission.WriteLine("Type: " & typ)
    Mission.WriteLine("Requirement: " & req1)
    Mission.WriteLine("Requirement: " & req2)
    Mission.WriteLine("Requirement: " & req3)
    Mission.Close()
    Console.WriteLine("Written")
    'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
End Sub
```

first of all pal, you were passing the parameters as objects!!, second you dont have permission to save to c root directory unless you have administrator privilege, third the threading part at the end is completely useless, its blocking the UI and don't add up to any benefit.
at last but not least.

good luck

Comment: Thanks pal, got it figured out. The Threading part was so i could see that it was writing the file, before exiting the console.